# subject agreement in participle clauses

Tags: participles

consider this sentence:

> I totally agree with the concept of schooling the offenders **while**
> **serving time in prison**

we do know that clauses with prepositions (after, by, ...) + ing and conjunctions(when, while) + ing are common in writing and that the implicit (or implied?) subject of the participle phrases should be the same as the main clause. keeping that in mind, I would imagine that part in bold in the sentence above is problematic (while serving time in prison) since its implied subject refers back to "I", which is obviously not the meaning the writer intended to go for. additionally, I believe omitting "while" would set the sentence straight. Am I right to think that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks like a misplaced modifier or something similar. Like a lot of misplaced modifiers, it is vaguely funny,  it doesn't really affect understanding.

Omitting "while" would change the phrase into a reduced relative clause, which would fix it.  Or you could insert an explicit subject "... while they are serving time"

Comment: right I did guess omitting "while" would change the phrase into a reduced relative clause. on a separate note, what is the function of "while serving ...."? it's obviously not a relative clause, right?

Comment: while is a subordinator. It indictates that the two clauses occur at the same time.  So "I agree... at the same time as I am serving time"